# Как взять переменные env в Vue 3 без дополнительных компонентов?

Tags: vue.js, .env

Есть такая проблема.

На `Vue 3` хочу взять переменные из файла `.env` без дополнительных компонентов. Как к примеру `dotenv`.

В доке не могу найти как это измениловсь в `Vue 3`.

Где то нашел что в `.env` нужно прописать так `VUE_APP_URL="http://site.loc"` что бы `vue` понял это.

```
console.log(process.env);
```

Результат пустой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто может подсказать как это работает?

Comment: А если установить пакет `dotenv` и вверху mix'a указать `require('dotenv').config();` ? и после этого в енв добавлять префикс MIX_APP_URL (не заменить APP_URL а указать второй, хотя и заменить попробуйте) ссылка на доку https://laravel.com/docs/master/mix#environment-variables судя по доке пакет можно и не ставить

Comment: @DmitriiSedov Ну да можно кастом . Но надо синтаксисом `vue 3`

Comment: Я просто к тому что при обновлении ларавель, он и мих меняет, а env как раз laravel mix превращает по идее.  Может не во vue дело? Просто в оф доке надо у параметра MIX_ добавить. Причина проста иначе на фронт попадет всё из енв, пароли и явки. А так только Mix параметры

Comment: @DmitriiSedov В итоге вообще `laravel` не причем. `.env` файл может быть везде.

Comment: _«Результат пустой»_ - попробуй вывести в консоль не `process.env`, а `process.env.VUE_APP_URL` :) _«как это работает?»_ - если не вдаваться в детали, это работает примерно как строковая замена,\ на этапе сборки.

Comment: @yar85 вообще то мне и это нужно. Но все ровно результата нет.

Comment: Хм, странно... должно выводиться. Хотя я не работал с laravel, и не могу точно сказать что меняется в связке с ним. vue-cli используется? env-файлик точно подхватывается этим инструментом (файл в корне проекта, или ...)?

Comment: @yar85 нет дело не в `laravel` есть ՝․env՝ и по логике по префиксам `vue` должен видеть переменные.

Comment: Должен, да. А раз не видит - то либо vue-cli (с dotenv под капотом) не применяется, либо эта утилита по каким-то причинам не читает env-файлик.

Comment: @yar85 может в версии баг есть. Не понятно.

Comment: Можешь добавить в вoпрос вывод команды `vue inspect module.plugins > dump-webpack-plugins.js`? После ее выполнения должен появиться файлик, его содержимое может пролить свет на проблему. В частности, интересен сгенерированный конфиг define-plugin'а. Хотя если vue-cli не подцепляет файл, это не особо поможет((